# DataGrid VB.NET 2005 URL writing

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have DataGrid and I have a hyperlink field but I want to send some information with this link by using URLwriting. I have tried this, but it's not working. So, please help me out.

```
~/Logout.aspx?ID="row.Cells(1).Text"
```

I want to send the value of data grid's column but I am getting "row.Cells.Text" instead of receiving the value of this. So I want to know how I would be able to get the value of this column.

Comment: your code-snipped would'nt even compile... I suggest to post a more meaningful part.

Comment: As a start, have a look at following link: http://authors.aspalliance.com/aspxtreme/webforms/controls/addinghyperlinkfieldstogridview.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
"~/Logout.aspx?ID=" & row.Cells(1).Value
```

See if that gets you what you want.

A little more clarification would be nice if this isn't what you are looking for.